# Change the form value on submit javascript

Tags: javascript

I have looked around and tried to follow other examples on this site but I cant get this to work.

I have a form a want to change the search value of when the user searches, for example when the user clicks 'search' change the value to 'dog'.

```
<form id="searchform" class="searchform" action=“” method="get" role="search">
<div>
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
    <input id="s" type="text" name="s" value=""></input>
    <input id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="Search"></input>
</div>
```

Can anyone show me how using javascript?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Right now the form is submitted, do you want to prevent the form from submitting and just change the value of the input ?

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself? Could you please share this code with us?

Comment: The problem is that you are overwriting your "submit" function.  You need to hook the "onSubmit" event one way or another.  What you are doing is just making it so the default `submit()` can't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the onsubmit function:

```
document.getElementById('searchform').onsubmit = function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('s');
    txt.value = "dog";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onsubmit` attribute of form. Make sure the submit input field has a name attribute `submit`

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
   ...
   <input id="searchsubmit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function validateForm(formObj) {
    // You can do any validation and return false if something invalid.

    // If everything is okay, just disable submit button and change the value.
    formObj.submit.disabled = true;
    formObj.submit.value = 'Searching...Please Wait...';
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#searchform').on('submit', function() {
    $(this.s).val('dog');
  });
});
```